# Chrome only error : Blocked a frame with origin "https://apis.google.com" from accessing

Tags: google-chrome, cross-domain

I have followed the google+ api's [guidelines](https://developers.google.com/+/web/) to put a signin button in my web app. It works with Firefox but not with Chrome : I get this same origin error :
`Blocked a frame with origin "https://apis.google.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://mysite.com".`
And I have declared `https://mysite.com` as a "javascript" origin in the https://console.developers.google.com.

I don't get it, it's their browser and thei api's doesn't work with it...
Can you help me overcome this cross-domain problem with Chrome  ?

Comment: I'm getting this same error, did you find a resolution?

Comment: @marty331 no I didn't ! maybe we'll end up with someone helping here !

Answer (score 1):

(This is more of a comment than a full answer but I don't have sufficient reputation to comment.)

I ran into the same problem following their python sample app instructions, also: https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/python

I had a couple Chrome extensions running that can modify page content: JSONView and StayFocusd. After disabling these extensions and trying again, it worked for me. Now I oddly can't seem to repro the problem even with the extensions re-enabled.

Seems worth a try?

Answer (score 0):

I overcame the problem by disabling any chrome extensions that I had installed that read and change the rendered HTML and ones that rewrite page headers and inject an sort of JavaScript in to the page.

One such extension(the one causing my `Blocked a frame with origin "https://apis.google.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://example.com` error) was namely Ripple Emulator (Beta) 0.9.15
A browser based html5 mobile application development and testing tool which "Reads and changes the all your data on the websites you visit" as it states in the extensions permission details.

Another such extension I disabled was ModHeader 1.2.4 Modify the Request Headers which also "Reads and changes the all your data on the websites you visit".

Just have a look at your Chrome extensions and eliminate any you suspect modifying pages.